# Java Spring Boot application to toggle between data sources (Configuration Classes)

Tags: java, spring-boot, feature-flags

I have a Java Spring Boot application currently connected to an on premises database. I am trying to figure out how to toggle between the existing datasource and a new one I have added. I have both data sources added in the application yml and defined in 2 (Config classes). I want to add logic to determine which one to use, a simple if-statement.

Comment: Toggle datasources how? During runtime?

Comment: I am using Feature toggles so essentially yes. Based on if the toggle is true I want to use a different datasource.My problem is I have configs for both data sources set up. Spring boot wont start the Tomcat server because it doesn't know which one to use